# VirtualDub Deshaker Error

Tags: virtualdub

So I'm trying to run Deshaker on some video straight from a Canon 60D in MOV format. I followed the steps in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NK8kyiDNTSo) to enable MOV support in VirtualDub. Sems to work well, but I keep getting this error about two-thirds of the way through Deshaker's first pass:

[image: VirtualDub Deshaker Error]

I really have no clue what to do. I did some research, but can't find anything useful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a software error. Your best bet would probably be to get a clean version of VirtualDub and retry the steps to enable .MOV support. Alternatively, you could also convert the .MOV to another format such as jpg sequence.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried starting fresh and I got the same error. Also, the conversion tool I use is Handbrake, and I can't find a way to convert video to AVI, which is what I'd prefer.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the same thing I'm using Avisynth instead as an input:

1. [Download](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Main_Page) and install Avisynth.
2. Install latest Quicktime 7.
3. Download [Quicktime Import](http://www.avisynth.nl/users/warpenterprises/) plugin for Avisynth and copy dll file in the Avisynth plugin folder.
4. Create Avisynth script file that describes you video as detailed in the Avisynth [Getting Started](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Getting_started), for example:

   > QTInput("D:\Folder\File_path.MOV", audio=true)
5. Open this Avisynth script file with "File" -> "Open Video File..." from VirtualDub.
6. Use VirtualDub with the [Deshaker plugin](http://www.guthspot.se/video/deshaker.htm) as usual.

With this input plugin reading my .MOV files I can stabilize any video through VirtualDub and Deshaker. I hope this will work for you as well.